# Real logarithm of a real matrix?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, logarithms, matlab, real-numbers

What is the real logarithm of
\begin{equation} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}? \end{equation}

I know it exists via this theorem (found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence)):

> A real matrix has a real logarithm if and only if it is invertible and each Jordan block belonging to a negative eigenvalue occurs an even number of times.

*(If you know of a general algorithm for this then that would be very helpful).*

Comment: What does this question have to do with Matlab?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom. Good point. My initial problem was that logm in MATLAB was only returning complex matrices. I would like a function that returns me real matrices. If you know of something like this in MATLAB then I would be interested. I was surprised when I couldn't find one, seeing as the question is very applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
}
$$
There exists a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = B$, where $B$ is given by
$$
B = 
\pmatrix{
-I & I\\
0 & -I
}
$$
Where $I$ here is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.

Now, starting from the other end, we define
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}, \quad
X = \pmatrix{\pi J & I\\0 & \pi J}
$$
we then have
$$
e^X = \pmatrix{e^{\pi J} & e^{\pi J}\\0 & e^{\pi J}} = \pmatrix{-I & -I\\0 & -I}
$$
Now, there exists a matrix $Q$ such that $Qe^{X}Q^{-1} = B$.

---

All together, we have
$$
A = PBP^{-1} = PQe^{X}Q^{-1}P^{-1} \implies\\
A = \exp[(PQ)X(PQ)^{-1}]
$$
Thus, $(PQ)X(PQ)^{-1}$ will be a matrix logarithm of $A$.

Comment: Take $P = \pmatrix{
0  &  1 &  0  &  0\\
0 &   0 &   0  &  1\\
1  &  0  &  0 &   0\\
0  &  0    & 1   & 0
}$

Comment: I get $e^J = \begin{pmatrix} cos(1) & -sin(1) \\ sin(1) & cos(1) \end{pmatrix}$ so I get a different answer for $e^X$.

Comment: Sorry! Those should be $\pi J$

Comment: Fixed it now. See the latest edit

Comment: Take $Q= \pmatrix{-I\\&I}$

Comment: Note that $P,Q$ are orthogonal, so $(PQ)^{-1}=Q'P'$.

Comment: Omnomnomnom, you have been so incredibly helpful. Thank you for all the effort put into this. I can see that you get $A$ into a nice form and then you get $e^X$ into the same form and then we're done, but other than this I can't see how you got to this answer, or where your intuition lay. Are there any suggestions about how I might go about this for other matrices? There seems to be some block identity matrix trick. Thank you again.

Comment: It all comes down to block matrices. The idea I'm using is that if the Jordan blocks come in pairs, then the matrix has a Jordan canonical form made of $2\times 2$ blocks. Then, we take the matrix logarithm, using the matrix logarithm to take the logarithm of the $2\times 2$ blocks. Does that make sense?

Comment: Note that $\pi J$ is the matrix log of $-I$.

Comment: Yes it does. I have never come across the idea of a $2 \times 2$ block Jordan canonical form. I will think more about this. Thank you very much indeed.